# Select dynamic record mysql Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have following table "salary",And i want to select record according to checkbox selected ( dynamic )

Here is my table "salary"

```
id      userId      name        salary
1       10          xyz         1000
2       12          abc         6000
3       11          sbb         9588
4       15          pyl         3000
```

Here is view file

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url().'/Admin/searchUser'?>" name="myForm"  id="form_img" >
<?php 
$i="1";
foreach($users as $user) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
<td class="txa_c"><input name="check[]" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" ></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</form>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-pri1" value="Search" name="resume"  >
</tr>
</form>
```

In controller file

```
function searchUser()
{
    $result['crud'] = $this->Crud->getsearchUsers($_POST);
    echo "<pre>";print_R($result['crud']);
}
```

In Model file

```
function getsearchUsers()
{
    $ids=$_POST['check'];
        //echo "<pre>";print_R($ids);
        foreach($ids as $id)
        {
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('salary');
                $this->db->where('userIdid',$id);
                $row = $querys->result_array();
        }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any result in  `print_r($result['crud']);`

Comment: take everything out of the foreach loop, except the where function

Answer (score 0):

1. **submit** button should be the inside of closing form tag e.g.

> ```
> <form>
>  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-pri1" value="Search" name="resume">
> </form>
> ```

2. check if your Controller method is getting any Form POST array e.g.

> ```
> <?php
> function searchUser()
> {
>   // make sure form is submitted
>   // With CodeIgniter’s built in methods you can simply do this:
>   if ($this->input->post()) {
>       // or PHP method
>       // if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
>       // since the model method getsearchUsers don't have any input params
>       // no need to pass the inputs
>       $result['crud'] = $this->Crud->getsearchUsers();
>       // echo supports , separated statement too
>       echo '<pre>', print_r($result['crud']), '</pre>';
>   }
>   // show error that form is not submitted
>   die('Input Error: Please provide the valid inputs.');
> }
> ?>
> ```

3. make sure there is no 403 error (*CodeIgniter CSRF token because you
   are using POST*)
4. you can also use built-in '***where_in***' to pass multiple where
   conditions in your Model

> ```
> <?php
> function getsearchUsers()
> {
>   // returns all post items with xss filter
>   $ids_array = $this->input->post('check', true);
>
>   $this->db->select('*');
>   $this->db->from('salary');
>   $this->db->where_in('userId', $ids_array);
>   // produces: WHERE userId IN ('1', '2')
>
>   $query = $this->db->get();
>
>   // check if records found
>   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
>       $row = $query->result_array();
>       // The $query result object will no longer be available
>       $query->free_result();
>
>       return $row;
>   }
>   // no record found
>   return FALSE;
> }
> ?>
> ```

5. most important ***Always sanitize your users input before to use***.